# Facebook comment integration failure

Tags: facebook

I am doing facebook integeration. When I login, the widget does not reload. Because of that I am unable to post comments. When I reload the window it works fine. What I am doing wrong?

I am using the code below.

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({ appId: '217419501642964',
             status: true,
             cookie: true,
             xfbml: true,
             channelUrl:'https://creator.zoho.com/channel.html'});
    _ga.trackFacebook();   
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
            '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
   }())
</script>
```

TIA
Log

Comment: I logged in using the login button given by the facebook plugin

Answer (score 0):

Try rerendering the XFBML after the login:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
  FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('myfblogin'));
  // where myfblogin is the id of your <fb:login-button> element
});
```